# How to avoid computed field to run on entity delete?

Tags: entities

I have a computed field that does something based on field collection fields, saving the values in the database (standard behaviour).

The problem is that the code is ran also when the node is deleted, causing some errors on the site.

Is there a way I can intercept the operation (entity_delete) on my code so that I can provide a safe alternative on node delete (or, even better, the computed field is not ran at all) ?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your scenario as well as a code example?

Comment: Hello, I personally resolved going to look the error and finding a workaround for it (when you delete a node with embedded field collection fields, pretty strange things happens), but my question remains in its general term: can we make aware the code inside of a computed field that we are //deleting// a node, and not just updating it ?